# start external exe from Form then wait for it to produce a file, or close down

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to do something very simple, and I hope there is a simple way of doing it!

1. Start an external exe from my user form application at a button press (use `Process.Start()` for example?).
2. Wait in my application for this exe to produce a known file, or to close. (I don't need any other activity to be taking place in my application apart from this waiting)
3. If the exe has produced the required file it should be killed automatically (using `Process.Kill()` presumably)

At this stage my Form inputs should return to being active.

The started exe has its own UI which my user will utilise while it is active.
I think the crux of this will be to do the waiting effectively. I assume that I can start a timer loop which will watch for the appearance of the file and the closing down of the launched exe, every few hundred milliseconds.

The PC will be doing little else at the time, and simplicity wins out over efficiency in these circumstances I feel.

Comment: Hi Jamie - I have just solved the problem with the following code which works like a dream (so far!!  bit more testing to do before I am totally convinced) :-

Comment: Good to hear! If it does solve your question could you post it as the answer? This way other users who may be in a similar scenario as you will benefit from it.

Answer (score 4):

You have the basic idea.

1. `Process.Start` will launch the process.
2. [`Process.WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) will block until the application completes
3. You shouldn't need to kill it, as it will complete, based on your 2nd point (see above)

If the executable isn't actually completing successfully, you could also use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to watch for the output file changes, and then use [`Process.CloseMainWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx) or [`Process.Kill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx) to terminate it once the output is generated properly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`WaitForExit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) method on `Process` to wait for a process to exit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to watch for your new file and you can look for the [Process.Exited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event to see if your app has shut down.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the waiting without a loop. The API for "Process" has other options to accomplish the required task.

```
            var procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd", "/c " + @"ping 127.0.0.1 -n 10")
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            var proc = new Process { StartInfo = procStartInfo };
            result = await Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }, TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness);
```

The code is for .NET 4.5 so that your UI keeps responsive during the wait. If you want you can do the same with simple calls using .NET 4.0.
The Line of code that makes the process execution wait is : proc.WaitForExit();
In this example i am using shell command to execute. But you can invoke any executable process.

AND

A sample to watch the file in "Readonly mode" so that it don't give "Another process is using it" error

```
this.fileFullPath = filePath + @"\" + fileName;
        this.fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(filePath);
        this.fileSystemWatcher.Filter = fileName;
        this.fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;
        this.fileSystemWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileSystemWatcherCreated);
        this.fileSystemWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileSystemWatcherChanged);
        ////this.fileSystemWatcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(FileSystemWatcherError);
        ////this.fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileSystemWatcherRenamed);
        ////this.fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileSystemWatcherDeleted);
        this.fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

The last line "EnableRaisingEvents will make the event notification come true and "NotifyFilter" will help you watch for different attributes and behaviors of a directory or file.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Import System.Diagnostics, add it to your usings, and try this code:

```
Process extProc = new Process();
extProc.StartInfo.FileName = "extProc.exe";
extProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "argument string";
extProc.Exited += new EventHandler(extProc_Exited);
extProc.Start();
```

Then handles the exited event

```
private void extProc_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Process thisProc = (Process)sender;
     if(thisProc.ExitCode == 1)
     {
         // success
     }
     else 
     {
         // error encountered
     }
}
```